# How do I use LDC (D Compiler) with Code::Blocks? Specifically, how do I use the linker?

Tags: codeblocks, d, ldc

I have been using CodeBlocks with the Digital Mars D compiler and the LLVM Clang compiler for some time without any problems.  Now I need to use the LDC D compiler and am having problems with the linker invocation.

I get the following output:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in test (compiler: LLVM D Compiler)---------------

ldc2.exe  -g    -I"C:\Program Files\LDC\ldc2-1.13.0-windows-x64\bin" -c hello.d -of=obj\Debug\hello.o
ldc2.exe -L-L"C:\Program Files\LDC\ldc2-1.13.0-windows-x64\lib" -of=bin\Debug\test.exe obj\Debug\hello.o   
Error: unrecognized file extension o
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

The compile step seems to work fine, but specifying ldc2.exe as a linker clearly fails.

Similarly, using `ldmd2.exe` and `lld-link.exe` in CodeBlocks' linker specification produce similar errors.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Code::Blocks is using the `.o` extension for object files on Windows, while the linker driver in the compiler frontend is probably expecting object files to have the `.obj` extension, which is more common on Windows.

I'm not familiar with Code::Blocks or how it interfaces with D compilers, but you can try checking to see if it has a setting to control what extension is used for object files. This may be a bug (or, simply, lacking Windows support) in whatever code is responsible for building D compiler command lines in Code::Blocks.

Comment: Спасибо.  The linker driver expects .obj but the compiler emits .o.  Interestingly, clang emits and the linker driver expects .o.

Comment: Will look at fixing lld-link.